# openpyxl hyperlink for loop

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a list of urls (100s) that I need to append to Column A as a link. This is a sample code of my for loop.

```
urlLinks = ['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']

max1 = ws.max_row
column = 1

for info in urlLinks:

    print(info)
    try:
        page.cell(row=max1, column=column).value = '=HYPERLINK("'+info+'","'+info+'")'

    except:
        pass



wb.save(filename = workbook_name)
```

I can get one link to work at a time, but I need to append 100s of urls.

```
info = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

page.cell(row=2, column=1).value = '=HYPERLINK("'+info+'","'+info+'")'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% what you are asking, but my guess is you want those links in separate rows in your excel workbook. If so, your row number can vary inside your loop, like so

```
urlLinks = ['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']

max1 = ws.max_row
column = 1

for info in urlLinks:

    print(info)
    try:
        page.cell(row=max1, column=column).value = '=HYPERLINK("'+info+'","'+info+'")'
        max1+=1 # here you increment max1 so output will go to the next row
    except:
        pass



wb.save(filename = workbook_name)
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. After adding max1=+1 to try and updating max1 = 1, I was able to generate the links.

Comment: Glad I could help.